# How to get only two element from html in same attribute?

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

i want parsing website using htmlagilitypack on aspx

below is my code

```
var html = @"http://test.com";
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
var htmlDoc = web.Load(html);

var htmlNodes = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='tableclass']//tr")
    .Where(x => !x.Attributes["id"].Value.Contains("tableid"));
```

when this code is executed, all 'tr' from HTMLtable are returned.

below is One of returned HTML

```
<tr bgcolor="gray">
    <td align="center" height="40">123</td>

    <td align="center" width="56">
        <div>
            <img src="http://img.test.com/img.jpg" height="10" border="0" />
        </div>
    </td>

    <td style="padding-left:3px;"><a href="/detail/detail.php?key=1234">THIS_1</a></td>

    <td style="padding-left:3px;"><a href="/detail/detail.php?key=1234">THIS_2</a></td>

    <td style="padding-left:3px;"><a href="/detail/add.php?site=1234"><font color='red'>blah</font></a></td>

    <td align="center"><a href="/board/board.php?id=1">0</a></td>

    <td align="center"><a href="/detail/detail.php?key=1234">0</a></td>

    <td align="center"><a href="/board/board.php?id=1">0</a></td>

    <td align="center"><a href="/board/board.php?id=1">0</a></td>
</tr>
```

## I Only want two td (THIS_1, THIS_2) InnerText

below is my wrong code

```
foreach (var node in htmlNodes)
{
    var str1 = node.ChildNodes["td"].InnerHtml;
    var str2 = node.SelectNodes(".//td[@style='padding-left:3px;']");
}
```

I want to Put [THIS_1 in str1] and [THIS_2 in str2].

Answer (score 0):

Try get elements by index. For example:

```
foreach (var node in htmlNodes)
{
    var str1 = node.SelectSingleNode("td[3]").InnerText;  // THIS_1
    var str2 = node.SelectSingleNode("td[4]").InnerText;  // THIS_2
}
```

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection.this[string].get returning NULL T.T

Comment: Fix! 

                var str1 = node.SelectSingleNode("td[3]").InnerText;
                var str2 = node.SelectSingleNode("td[4]").InnerText;

Thank you!!